# How to observe statusChanges/valueChanges formArray?

Tags: angular

I have a problem with reactive form when trying to observe statusChanges/valueChanges with form-array.
When the values of form changes, i'd to subscribe and do something when form changes.
I have form like this

```
form = new FormGroup({ users: new formArray ([
       new FormGroup({name: new FormControl(''), 
        total: new FormControl('')})
]) })
```

I've tried to observe them like this but its not working.

```
ngOnInit() { 
this.form.statusChanges.subscribe(res => {console.log('result status')}));
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {console.log('result value')}))
  }
```

Any idea how to observe them when status or value in the form is changing?

Sorry for my English.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: your code works (well you has a type errors: (it's FormArray -the first UpperCase and you had add an extra parenthesis when subscribe: see one [stackblitz with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rzm4xe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi @Eliseo 
Thanks for pointing out. I fix the typo but its still not working...

Answer (score 0):

Need to specify the group

```
 this.form.get('users').valueChanges.subscribe( x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: really not, you can listen the whole form

Comment: Hi, 
thank for your kind response.
I need to check the whole form in order to identify which values/status have been change.
Do you have any suggestion?